# Get children of three different parents in polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the model `Post`, that via polymorphism belongs to either `Organization`, `Team` or `User`.

For each parent I'm fetching the posts like this:

```
current_user.posts
current_user.organization.posts
current_user.team.posts
```

**How would I merge these queries returning a single AR object with all posts?**

I have tried the following:

```
Post.where(trackable: current_user).where(trackable: current_user.team) # returns 0 objects

current_user.posts + current_user.organization.posts # this returns an array
```

Comment: Have you tried something like: `Post.where(trackable: [current_user, current_user.organization, current_user.team])`?

Comment: It works! And I actually now discovered that I as well could use Rails 5 new .or like `Post.where(trackable: current_user).or(Post.where(trackable: current_user.team))`. But putting them in an array as you suggested is way cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Glad it worked. I posted it as an answer so you can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Post.where(trackable: [current_user, current_user.organization, current_user.team])
```